# How to access all properties when BehaviorSubject declared with multiple interfaces?

Tags: typescript, generics, rxjs

I have several interfaces as below:

```js
export interface INT1 {
   prop1: string;
   prop2: string;
}

export interface INT2 {
   prop1: string;
   prop3: string;
}

export interface INT3 {
   prop1: string;
   prop4: string;
}
```

Now I am trying to declare a `BehaviorSubject` that returns one of the three interfaces above:

```js
private _mySub$ = new BehaviorSubject<INT1 | INT2 | INT3>(undefined);
```

This doesn't work, because if I access the `BehaviorSubject` value, I only find the shared properties (in this case only `prop1`).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen - if it's a subject of any one of those three types, prop1 is the only property that's guaranteed to exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code. Since `_mySub$` could be a `BehaviorSubject` of type `INT1`, `INT2`, or `INT3`, static analysis can only guarantee that `_mySub$` has property `prop1` in all cases. It would be incorrect to infer the existence of other properties without narrowing the type.

If you know for a particular context that the `BehaviorSubject` will always return exactly one of the interfaces, then you could use a more specific declaration such as:

```js
private _mySub$ = new BehaviorSubject<INT1>({prop1: '1', prop2: '2'});
```

## Type Guards

A common solution for handling broad type-definitions is to use [TypeScript Type Guards](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-type-guards/).

#### Example: User-defined Type Guard for INT1

```js
function instanceOfINT1(object: any): object is INT1 {
  return 'prop2' in object;
}
```

Using the type guard, you could safely access `prop2` when the `BehaviorSubject` emitted an `INT1`:

```js
class MyClass {
  private _mySub$ = new BehaviorSubject<INT1 | INT2 | INT3>({prop1: '1', prop2: '2'});

  constructor() {
    this._mySub$.subscribe( (val) => {
      if (instanceOfINT1(val)) {
        console.log(`val.prop2: ${val.prop2}`);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you could declare a "base" interface with shared prop1 property.

```
export interface BASE {
   prop1: string;
}

export interface INT2 extends BASE {
   prop3: string;
}

export interface INT3 extends BASE {
   prop4: string;
}
```

Secondly, you can use typescript assertion:

```
const int3: INT3 = obj as INT3;
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions